# Rails TimeWithZone and leap years

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

Today is Feb 29th: the day our tests broke.

Our tests are failing because these tests do things that, in the end, can be compared to a command like this: `Time.zone.now - 1.year + 1.year`. And it happens to be *NOT* equal to `Time.zone.now`.

Why does this happen? Why isn't ActiveSupport able to handle leap years in calculations like that? Doesn't it work with timestamps, that would prevent this sort of problem from happening?

Comment: If you are testing it today, you have a bad luck... Today is the 29th of February, which exists only every 4 years. So `Time.zone.now` + `1.year` will get you to the 28th of February because the 29th does not exists for the year 2017. `1.year.from_now` will also return the 28th of Feb. 2017

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But why isn't `Time.zone.now + 1.year` equal to March 1st, for instance? In my opinion that would be more appropriate.

Comment: Time.zone.now - 365.days + 365.days seems to work though...

Answer (score 0):

You could use 4 years instead of 1 for the same effect. (Note: - 1.day because it is 1st March right now)

```
(Time.zone.now - 1.day) - 4.year + 4.year
 => Mon, 29 Feb 2016 15:12:58 UTC +00:00
```

It may be worth noting that (below), regardless of date.

```
Time.zone.now
 => Tue, 01 Mar 2016 15:11:51 UTC +00:00 
Time.zone.now == Time.zone.now - 1.year + 1.year
 => false
```

Unless you use beginning_of_day:

```
(Time.zone.now - 1.day).beginning_of_day == ((Time.zone.now - 1.day) - 4.year + 4.year).beginning_of_day
 => true
```

Also, it depends what you are actually trying to do... Why would you want to test `Time.now - 1.year + 1.year` ?

Also...

```
1.year == 365.days
 => false 
1.year == 365.25.days
 => true
```

Comment: `Time.zone.now == Time.zone.now - 1.year + 1.year` will never work, you must store `Time.zone.now` in a variable.

Comment: Yes, true, but it works for date: `Date.today == Date.today - 1.year + 1.year`